# Private Messages NOT are reaching the subscribers

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm Extending this [git'let](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/master/complete) project to send/receive private messages - targeted only to specific subscribed users. I'm able to send it, but subscribers are not receiving them. I've added the forked full code [here](https://github.com/anandchakru/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/master/complete), below is a snippet of just the *important parts* of the code.

**Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private SessionBasedHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler).withSockJS();
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    public SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;
    private Set<String> users = new HashSet<>();

    @GetMapping("/subscribe4PrivateMsgs")
    public @ResponseBody String enablePrivateMessages(HttpSession session) {
        String sessionId = session.getId();
        users.add(sessionId);
        return sessionId;
    }
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    private void sendPrivateMessageToScubscribers() {
        users.forEach((sessionId) -> {
            SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
            headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
            headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
            String msg = sessionId + ":" + GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            Greeting response = new Greeting(msg);
            //Tried the following to Send Private Message, but it doens't works
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/private", response,
                    headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
            //The following reached UI successfully - but to all users
            /*response.setContent("Public Msg:: " + msg);
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", response);*/
        });
    }
}
```

**UI:**

```
function connect() {
    $.get("/subscribe4PrivateMsgs", function(userId) {
        var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting('Received Public Msg: ' + JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/private', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting('1 Received Private Msg: ' + JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/'+userId+'/queue/private', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting('2 Received Private Msg: ' + JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this line was causing issues.

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/private", response, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

Changing it to

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/private", response);
```

resolved the issue. [Github](https://github.com/anandchakru/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/tree/master/complete) updated with a working copy.